# Syntax error in if / else command

Tags: shell-script

What is wrong with this command? There seams to be a syntax error, but I don't see where:

```
sh -c 'mongodump --host mongo_db --gzip --db db $$(if [ $TYPE = "hour" ]; then echo "--archive=/backup/hour/$$(date +"%H").gz"; elif [ $TYPE = "day" ]; then echo --archive=/backup/day/$$(date +"%d").gz; fi)'
```

I need to set archive name depending on TYPE variable.

- If type is "hour", output should be e.g. `/backup/hour/10.gz`
- If type is "day", output should be e.g. `/backup/day/1.gz`
- If type is "month", output should be e.g. `/backup/2017-09.gz`

Comment: What's up with the double `$$`s? You probably wanted `$(...)`.

Comment: and probably "$TYPE" instead of $TYPE in if block

Comment: There are millions of guides on how to debug.   Read as many of them as you need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sh -c 'echo mongodump --host mongo_db --gzip --db db --archive="$(
    case "$1" in 
        hour)  f="%H";; 
        day)   f="%d";; 
        month) f="%Y-%m";; 
        *)     f="unknown"; set -- "";; 
    esac
    date "+/backup/$1/$f.gz"
)"' x "$TYPE"
```

- DRY
- `case` is more readable than long `if/elif/elif...`
- The `x "$TYPE"` is a method to pass the "outer" variable into the sh body without playing quoting games. The "x" becomes $0 in the sh body, and $TYPE becomes $1.
- newlines are allowed inside `$(...)`
- You're allowed to put non-`%`-directives in the `date` format string.

Answer (score 1):

You have unquoted variables (`$TIME`) and syntax errors (`$$(...)`). Furthermore, if `TYPE` is a shell variable (rather than an environment variable), its value won't be visible at all inside the single quoted `sh -c` script.

The statement should look something like

```
sh -c "mongodump --host mongo_db --gzip --db db \"$(if [ \"$TYPE\" = \"hour\" ]; then echo \"--archive=/backup/hour/$(date +%H).gz\"; elif [ \"$TYPE\" = \"day\" ]; then echo --archive=/backup/day/$(date +%d).gz; fi)\""
```

(or something...)

It's problematic to get the quoting right since you'd like the shell to expand `$TYPE` in the innermost subshell and still have it double-quoted.

If you don't need the `sh -c` (there's nothing requiring it that I can see), it becomes a bit easier on the eyes:

```
mongodump --host mongo_db --gzip --db db "$(if [ "$TYPE" = "hour" ]; then echo "--archive=/backup/hour/$(date +%H).gz"; elif [ "$TYPE" = "day" ]; then echo "--archive=/backup/day/$(date +%d).gz"; fi)"
```

However, since this would give an empty command substitution if `$TYPE` is neither `day` nor `hour`, I'd suggest you do this instead:

```
case "$TYPE" in
    hour) archive="/backup/hour/$(date +%H).gz" ;;
    day)  archive="/backup/day/$(date +%d).gz"  ;;
    *)
       printf 'Error: Unknown TYPE "%s"\n' "$TYPE" >&2
       exit 1 ;;
esac

sh -c "mongodump --host mongo_db --gzip --db db --archive=$archive"

# or just

mongodump --host mongo_db --gzip --db db --archive="$archive"
```

This makes it a whole lot easier to read, understand, and to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

If `TYPE` is unset, empty, or consists entirely of whitespace, your statement boils down to `if [  = "hour" ]` which is a syntax error.

Since you're using `sh`, the common workaround for this is a prefix: `if [ "x$TYPE" = "xhour" ]`

You can't simply use weak quotes, because a `""` will also resolve to `if [  = "hour" ]`; at least with `sh`.  `bash` when using the more robust double-brace syntax (e. g. `if [[ "$TYPE" = "hour" ]]`) will do the right thing without resorting to prefixes or suffixes.

Comment: But TYPE has always a value in my setting...

Comment: You might think it does; are you certain?  add `echo TYPE is $TYPE;` immediately before your `if`.

Comment: I'd recommend `"x$TYPE"` not `x$TYPE` to protect against unexpected whitespace

Comment: @roaima `x` should not be necessary in double-quotes.

Comment: @Gordon try with `TYPE=-z` and you'll see that you do need the `x`.

Comment: @roaima `TYPE=-z; [ "$TYPE" = "hour" ] && echo "oops"` (with quotes but without "x") works ok in every shell I have handy (which is to say it doesn't print "oops" or any error).